# querying process load in Python

Tags: python, process, metrics

Is there any portable way for a Python process to query its own system CPU load?

If the "ps" command exists I could run it and parse the results, but that's less than desirable.

Answer (score 3):

you can use [psutil](https://code.google.com/p/psutil/):

```
import os
import psutil

pid = os.getpid()
p = psutil.Process(pid)
pct = p.get_cpu_percent(interval=1.0)
print(pct)
```

Answer (score 0):

[Guppy / Heapy](http://guppy-pe.sourceforge.net/) might be useful for you, but there are versioning issues and it may not do everything you want.